# OnAuthorization Called Twice When Returning Unauthorized Status

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute

I've implemented my own `AuthorizeAttribute` since I'm passing my Authorization Token in through a cookie.

```
public class ValidateToken : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
            CookieHeaderValue authToken = headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault();

            CookieState authCookie = authToken.Cookies.Where(p => p.Name == "AUTH-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault();

            actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authCookie.Value);

            bool isAuth = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);

            if (!base.IsAuthorized(actionContext)){
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
```

My  **problem** is, inside `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` when I return `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` the function `OnAuthorization` is called again which then calls `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` after the auth check fails.  On the second call the Web API returns with a `401` however I get the login screen on my front end 
[image]

which I don't want one.  I just want a 401 returned as usual.  The weird thing is if I replace `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` with `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden` then the function is not called a second time and returns immediately.

**Edit** I've discovered that `OnAuthorization` is called twice and the login form is shown because in Angular I am passing `withCredentials: true` for my cookies.  So I need to figure out why `withCredentials: true` is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure **Anonymous Authentication** is **enabled** and **Windows Authentication** is **disabled**.

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```